# Why is the warning “Allow this website to open a program on your computer” different for some domains?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

In an enterprise environment we have an application that simply opens outlook using  JavaScript, it executes the following code from a iframe:

```
top.location.href="mailto:my@email.com&subject=some subject"
```

When I use Internet Explorer 11, in non-production environments, I have the following warning and I can click on Allow and everything goes OK.

[image: This image is just an example]

(this image is just an example from internet, our domains are not exposed on internet )

The problem is for production environments (same application version), the URL is different. When I click on the same link, I get the message above but the Allow button is disabled and I cannot click it.

Please note that production certificates are valid and signed correctly.

Why is the Allow button disabled for production?

Comment: Do mailto: links on other sites launch a mail user agent (MUA) in production?

Comment: Do the production machines use any kind of antivirus or proxy? Does http://xion.io/post/code/js-mailto-urls.html help?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the difference between the computers lies in the registry.

This prompt can be disabled by the following registry edits:

HKCU: For the current user:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\mailto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

HKLM: For the entire computer:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\mailto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

HKLM: For the entire 64-bit computer used by 32-bit programs:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\mailto]
"WarnOnOpen"=dword:00000000
```

If you do not wish to totally disable the prompt for `mailto:`,
you should look for other differences, such as with the installed
security software.

Answer (score 1):

**Plain English Answer:** Your production/enterprise system is more paranoid. They likely have sensitive stuff and/or don't trust their users to not click on things so it's made harder.

**Technical Answer:**

I believe this has to do with IE security zones & a GPO they've set that hardens/overrides the default so you'll need to work with the domain admins in that production requirement. They likely will want to add your website/webapp to a trusted sites list OR loosen up their setting that controls [`mailto` URI (protocol in Windows GUI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

- GUI location of zones/setting: Internet Options, Security, with Internet selected click Custom level, scroll down to Miscellaneous (about halfway):

  [image]
- [GPO locations](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#1557) (depending on zone & user vs computer config [override]):

  - `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Internet Zone\`
  - `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Trusted Sites Zone\`
  - `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\Trusted Sites Zone\`

[This post by Microsoft might help explain better](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Managing-the-quot-Launching-Applications-and-Unsafe-Files-quot/ba-p/372583)
*I don't think this has to do with web/SSL certificates as its just a `mailto`, the issue lies in allowing a website/browser to interact with applications on your local machine (which is configured in browser or PC as a website should never get to control that)*